# DELETE request on Stash tags

Tags: python, rest, request, tags, bitbucket-server

This question is similar to [Git delete branch without cloning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866222/git-delete-branch-without-cloning/31866582#31866582) and overall very simple, but for some reason I can't find the right answer.

I am using Stash REST API to update tags in Stash repository. To send POST request and add new tag is easy (for example with python requests, but could be same with curl):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import requests

url = '.../rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/tags'

data = {'force': 'false',
        'message': 'Updated tag',
        'name': 'LATEST_SUCCESSFUL',
        'startPoint': 'ffffff',
        'type': 'LIGHTWEIGHT'}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, header=headers)
```

This works ok, but I want to keep option of remotely deleting this tag. According to documentation https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.6/stash-scm-git-rest.html?_ga=1.6600434.1354597480.1483944905 this should work:

```
url = '.../rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/tags/LATEST_SUCCESSFUL
r = requests.delete(url)
```

But I get 404 error here. So the question is, what is the correct way to access (and delete) single tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple, for tag delete requests should hit

```
rest/git/1.0/...
```

instead of

```
rest/api/1.0/...
```

but the latter one works fine for get requests.